How to add timezone and day light saving info into google protobuf Timestamp?
I'm using google protobuf timestamp for recording purpose in python, however, when I compare the timestamp, I would need to know the timezone and day light saving information associated with every timestamp. Is there any good way to do that? Thanks!

Timestamp's represent "point in time independent of any time zone or calendar".
Many of the languages that implement Protobufs also provide an implementation for Timestamp (e.g. Go's `timestamppb') that includes language-specific methods to convert to/from the language's datetimes and these can be then be used for language-specific time comparisons etc.
Worst case (if you can't use the language-specific implementations described above), you can compare the Timestamp's seconds and then nanoseconds values to order (e.g. before|after).
The documentation provides a Python example (see "Example 5").
Alternatively:
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp

import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

ts = Timestamp()
ts.FromDatetime(dt)

print(ts)
print(ts.ToDatetime())
print(ts.ToJsonString())

Both examples depend on using protobuf
